# Building raw disk images: best way to delete files for compression?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-image

I'm building raw disk images (ie, dd, chroot to install linux). During the customization process I may delete files, use temporary files, etc.

What is the best way to delete these files to ensure the image is most compressible?

I'm assuming if I simply rm the file, it's just deleting records from the FAT to mark the blocks as available. This leaves the data in place, so when I gzip or bzip2 the image it still has to pack that data up. I assume things would be a lot tighter if I could tell the FS to write zeros to the blocks instead.

A bit of detail: these are CentOS 6.4 installs on ext4, but I would expect the answer applies to most linux distros using most file systems. The base filesystem I generate is via a command like `dd if=/dev/zero of=filesystem.image bs=1M count=10240`. A typical 10GB disk image from a vanilla install will compress down to roughly 500MB. I bet if I did a more aggressive cleanup of temp files and such, I could get it a lot tighter.

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/165070/how-to-zero-fill-a-virtual-disks-free-space-on-windows-for-better-compression/165074#165074 Specifically, I suggest `zerofree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoredache's comment got me on the right track (see [How to zero fill a virtual disk's free space on windows for better compression?](https://serverfault.com/questions/165070/how-to-zero-fill-a-virtual-disks-free-space-on-windows-for-better-compression/165074#165074)).

As far as I can tell, zerofree homepage is http://intgat.tigress.co.uk/rmy/uml/index.html. There are two things hosted here: the zerofree tool and a kernel patch. The kernel patch does not work with ext4, but adds the ability to set a mount flag to zero out files on delete. The zerofree program does work on ext4.

There are no zerofree CentOS 6 RPM's available, but I was able to compile it on CentOS6 using the CentOS5 srpm.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file/files containing only zeroes, to fill up the filesystem free space. The blocks marked as free will then be overwritten with zeroes.
Afterwards, delete these files.

Update:
Since this answer has been downvoted, I decided to test whether this is actually true or my knowledge is wrong. So far it looks like this is working as I expected.

I created two images with the same command as OP, except I made it 1G in size, since this is for testing purpouses:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=img1.im bs=1M count=1024
dd if=/dev/zero of=img2.im bs=1M count=1024
```

I then proceeded to format the image files as ext4, mount them on separate directories and copy two directories containing pictures on both images. One directory was 71M and the other — 461M. Afterwards, I deleted the 461M directory from both mountpoints.
So far all the actions were identical. I then left the first image alone and created a zerofile taking up all free space on the second one, deleting it afterwards:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=img2/zerofile bs=1K count=884644
rm img2/zerofile
```

`df` once again showed that the filesystems were filled the identically (system partitions removed for clarity) :

```
$ df
Filesystem                 1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0                    999320     62248    884644   7% /home/black/temp/img/img1
/dev/loop1                    999320     62248    884644   7% /home/black/temp/img/img2
```

After umounting and compressing both images with bzip2, the output of `ls` speaks for itself:

```
$ ls -lh
total 604M
-rw-r--r-- 1 black users 523M apr 19 11:56 fs1.im.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 black users  81M apr 19 11:56 fs2.im.bz2
```

Although this might take longer of bigger images than just zeroing out the space that was actually used for files, this method is simple, effective and uses only `dd` so no additional tools are needed.

Comment: Yes, it works, but dd'ing in a dd'ed image is a very slow way to do it. zerofree takes about 10 seconds on my build process.